# Trigger pipeline/job when merge request state changes (WIP to "ready")

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am currently trying to implement a pipeline using Gitlab ci. I defined my pipeline in a gitlab-ci.yml file to run my jobs. I am working on pipeline  where jobs are triggered by opened merge request. more specifically , non WIP and draft merge request. One of the most important condition is also that I want the job to be triggered and running when merge request changes state from WIP/draft to "ready".

Below is the closest way I found to do such thing.

```
integrationtest:
  stage: integrationtest
  only:
    - merge_requests
  except:
    variables:
      - $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE =~ /^WIP:.*/
```

Unfortunately, Now the only thing missing  is indeed the pipeline being triggered when WIP state changes.
Any idea to bypass this problem is more than welcome.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an open [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/25426) for you exact use case. There is a workaround with webhook integration mentioned in the last comment of this issue, maybe this will help you.